# Problem after uninstalling a module

Tags: module

I uninstalled a module using:

> admin > extension > module uninstall

and now I receive this error:

> 1146 Table 'zog_16659563_rff.wtbl5_tawkwidget' doesn't exist SQL=SHOW
>   FULL COLUMNS FROM `wtbl5_tawkwidget`

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe the developer has used PHP to drop the tables associated with the extension and made a mistake somewhere.

You'll need to go to PhpMyAdmin, search for the table `wtbl5_tawkwidget` and simply remove it.